# How to prove the nth backward difference is zero in polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a $k^{th}$ degree polynomial.

How do you infer the below equation -

$(-1)^{0} {k+1\choose 0} f(n) + (-1)^{1} {k+1\choose 1} f(n - 1) + \cdots+(-1)^{k+1}{k+1 \choose k+1}f(n-(k+1)) = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define, for any polynomial $P$, $DP(X)=P(X)-P(X-1)$. Note that clearly $\deg{DP} \leq \deg{P}$, and $\deg{D(X^n)} < n$. Thus, for any nonzero $P$, $\deg{DP} < \deg{P}$.

It follows by induction that if $\deg{P} \leq k$, then $D^{k+1}P=0$.

Now $(D^{k+1}f)(n)$ is more or less your expression.

Comment: What does $D(X^n)$ means?

Comment: Just the definition: $D(X^n)=X^n-(X-1)^n$.